# Why does air density increase with temperature?

Tags: density-altitude, environment

Why air density increases with increase in temperature , but this is opposite in case of liquid.

Comment: What makes you think it does? Have a look at [Density of air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air).

Comment: Density decreases as temperature increases. "Density altitude" increases as temperature increases because the altitude where you find the currently less dense air is would normally be found at higher altitude. The density altitude is just a reference height in comparison to standard conditions

Comment: Down voted because the question makes a false assumption.

Comment: Maybe the OP is confused with Boyle's law,
  a law stating that the pressure of a given mass of an ideal gas is inversely proportional to its volume at a constant temperature. In the case of aircraft flying in the Earth's atmosphere the volume is not constrained.

Comment: @Transistor   Yes you are right, I read this line in book on Avionics where they explained concept of duct propagation in radio waves using above mentioned air temp and density relation.

Answer (score 3):

As clarified in the comments, you are confused with Boyle's law, a law stating that the pressure of a given mass of an ideal gas is inversely proportional to its volume at a constant temperature.

In the case of aircraft flying in the Earth's atmosphere the volume is not constrained so pressure does not have to increase with temperature.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is false. Air density decreases with increasing temperature.